# Does limited time constitute maximum effort?

Tags: reference-request, time, idea

Have there been any philosophers who have emphasized or spoken about/around any of the following ideas?

- The idea that our limited time on Earth does/doesn't constitute a responsibility to 'make best use of' this time?
- The idea that our limited time on Earth should/shouldn't not be used as a justification  for acts carried out whilst alive?

I'm not particularly sure where these ideas have arisen from. It's something I would like to explore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many philosophers who have tackled these topics that to attempt to list them all would be an exercise in futility.  However, I'd recommend researching the Stoics and the Existentialists in particular as offering differing perspectives on how to approach life in the face of death.

It's also explicitly the subject of most of the Biblical book of Ecclesiastes:

https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Bible/Ecclesiastes.html